# Unable to retrieve metadata for model class file when add a controller in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am create a model in simple mvc application.After create model class file i am adding controller in solution.But i am not able to add it.

1 Here is model class file

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
    public class studentDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<student> students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2 also `web.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="studentDbcontext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

3 error i am facing...
[image: error i am facing...]

Comment: Chage your connection string to a code-first one `<add name="studentDbcontext" connectionString="data source=(local);initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am getting popup with this message **unable to retrive metadata for 'MvcApplication1.Models.student'.Unable to cast object to type.**